# Retrieve an answer from a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, logic-programming

Hello I am a beginner in Prolog and i have stuck in the following problem.
Here it goes , I have a "database" which gives me information about the school schedule
something like this :

`school(NameOfTeacher,([(Course,Day) ......]).`

When asking the following
`-? find(staff(NameOfTeacher,Course),Day)`

the answer should be `Day = (the day the course takes place)`. I manage to take an answer like `Day = (Course,Day)` but that it not what I want. Has anyone any idea of how to do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Prolog unification is a kind of bi-directional pattern matching, so you can use it to both create and decompose data structures:

```
?- Pair = (maths,monday), (_,Day) = Pair.
Pair = (maths, monday)
Day = monday
Yes
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm afraid i still don't get it, the result i get with what i've tried so far is of the following form: for example ?- find(staff(john,maths),Day). Day = (maths,monday), and it continues with the rest of the courses as well , Day = (physics,tue) then Day = (chemistry, friday). I'm pretty sure the problem is in the way i request the answer but can't figure it out